# I want to change the color of button when select in angular

Tags: angular

HTML File:

```
  <h1>Trade zone A</h1>
    <div class="horizontal-array">
      <label *ngFor="let shop_id of myArray">
        <button type="button" [value]="shop_id" 
      [ngClass]="{'selected': shop_id === selectedShopId, 'unavailable': shop_id === selectedShopId}" 
      (click)="onButtonClick(shop_id)">
      {{shop_id}}
    </button>
      </label>
    </div>
```

TS File :

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tradzone-a',
      templateUrl: './tradzone-a.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tradzone-a.component.css']
    })
    export class TradzoneAComponent {
      myArray: string[] = [];
    
      ngOnInit():void{
        this.selectedShopId = localStorage.getItem('selectedShopId');
        this.shop_id = this.selectedShopId;
      }
      
      constructor(private router:Router){
        for (let i = 1; i <= 116; i++) {
          const shop_id = `TA${i}`;
          console.log(`shop_id: ${shop_id}`);
          this.myArray.push(shop_id);
        }
        
      }
    
      shop_id: any;
      selectedShopId: any;
      onButtonClick(shop_id: any) {
        console.log(`Button clicked for item ${shop_id}`);
      
        if (this.shop_id === shop_id) {
          // Show alert if the same button is clicked again
          alert(`Shop ${shop_id} is already booked. Please choose another one.`);
          return;
        }
      
        // Change button classes
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.horizontal-array button');
        buttons.forEach((button: any) => {
          if (button.value === shop_id) {
            button.classList.remove('unavailable');
            button.classList.add('selected');
          } else if (button.classList.contains('selected')) {
            button.classList.remove('selected');
            button.classList.add('unavailable');
          } else {
            button.classList.remove('selected');
            button.classList.add('unavailable');
          }
        });
        
        // Store selected shop_id in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('selectedShopId', shop_id);
      
        // Navigate to stall-booking page
        if (this.shop_id !== shop_id) {
          this.router.navigate(['/stall-booking'], { queryParams: { shop_id: shop_id } });
          this.shop_id = shop_id;
        }
      }
    }
```

In my code it changes the color but it change only when i am selected.Means when i select one button it changes the color red but when i select another one it changes the previous color.I dont want to change the previous button color the above code is not changes the color please help to correct it.

Comment: Is this correct:  [ngClass]="{'selected': shop_id === selectedShopId, 'unavailable': shop_id === selectedShopId}" ? both selected and unavailable have saem condition?

Comment: I dont know where is the problem can you help?

Comment: Sure. What logic do you want to achieve in terms of button colors?

Comment: I want to change the button color when select first all the button colors are green then after select it becomes red.The above code is doing that but when i select another button it change the color of previous button to again green i want it red.So how i can acheive that.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you could solve your issue, buy using a buttonsState array, and based on that change de color accordingly:

```js
  myArray: string[] = ['id_1','id_2','id_3];
  buttonStates: boolean[] = [false, false, false];

  toggleButtonState(index: number): void {
    this.buttonStates[index] = !this.buttonStates[index];
  }
```

```html
 <div>
      <button *ngFor="let shopId of myArray; let i = index;"
              [ngClass]="{ 'seelcted': !buttonStates[i], 'unavailable': buttonStates[i] }"
              (click)="toggleButtonState(i)">
        {{ shopId }}
      </button>
    </div>
```